# EXCEL Formula_How to determine if the content of a cell is included in a range

Tags: excel-formula

Good afternoon, I'm working on a quality control report and I want to compare the content of one cell with a range of cells. For exemple,

```
piece1 | colour | OK  | OK  | OK
piece1 | weight | OK  | NOK | OK
piece1 | length | NOK | OK  | OK
piece1 |diameter| 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.1
piece2 | colour | NOK | OK  | NOK
piece2 | weight | OK  | NOK | OK
piece2 | length | NOK | OK  | OK
piece2 |diameter| 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.1
```

Then I've a range with all the "binary" type control like colour, weight, length. And I want the formula to check if this test is a binary control, if it is, then I should count the number of OK, if it's a numerical result (like diameter) I should calculate the average. So generally, my object is like this:

```
piece1 | colour | OK  | OK  | OK  | 3
piece1 | weight | OK  | NOK | OK  | 2
piece1 | length | NOK | OK  | OK  | 2
piece1 |diameter| 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.1 | 1.13
piece2 | colour | NOK | OK  | NOK | 1
piece2 | weight | OK  | NOK | OK  | 2
piece2 | length | NOK | OK  | OK  | 2
piece2 |diameter| 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.1 | 1.13
```

I've tried with `IFs` but there are lots of criteria so the formula became long. And so I wish to find a easier method (easier to read and maintain).

```
=IF(B2=U1:U3;COUNTIF(C1:E1;"OK");AVERAGE(C1:E1))
```

with the "binary" test name in U1 to U3. I've found that on the net but it doesn't work. So there're still things to correct. So if you've some idea or other methode to improve this one, please leave a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need checking the criteria, then you could do:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($U$1:$U$3,$B2)>0,COUNTIF($C2:$E2,"OK"),AVERAGE($C2:$E2))
```

This approach will count if the criteria is in the Range `U1:U3`. If so, then count the "OK"s, else `AVERAGE`.

But you could also have another approach. If `AVERAGE` has not values to average, then it will return `#DIV/0!` error. If so, then count the "OK"s.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE($C2:$E2),COUNTIF($C2:$E2,"OK"))
```